# Answer migrated from private beta not attributed

Tags: support, status-completed, migration, private-beta

> Original Question (I had the 2nd answer) - [What guidelines should I follow while designing a library?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/196151/what-guidelines-should-i-follow-while-designing-a-library)

Not too long ago, I was part of the Arduino private beta. Unfortunately it got closed down, and the answers were therefore migrated to other sites. Having had the foresight to create a EE.SE account, the answers migrated there are linked to my profile. However, after being notified one had been moved to Programmers.SE, I created an account there - but, even several weeks later, my answer doesn't belong to me. Is this a bug, or is it my fault for not creating an account first?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I fixed up the attribution, so you should have ownership of that answer back now.

Because Arduino.SE was closed, the question no longer has migration history (since it'd just lead nowhere), and that is likely why the answer wasn't properly associated with your account.